# save pdf file from web api with Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, character-encoding, base64

I need to support a legacy Access tool with some macros. I should send an xml as form attachment to a web api and receive a pdf.

I have no control on the other end.

When I submit the XML's created by the Access macro, vith the MSXML2 library, see texts like this in the final PDF:

`MÃ¡svalaki` should be `Másvalaki`

When I attach the VBA generated xml file in a Postman request, I get a correct PDF as response, so the file should be ok and I assume, I do something wrong either during submit or when I save the pdf file.

submit goes like this:

```
    http.Open "POST", url, False

    ' Set the content type header to multipart/form-data
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7e0dd540448"
    
    ' Create the form data body with the file
    Dim body As String
    body = "-----------------------------7e0dd540448" & vbCrLf
    body = body & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""action-xmlagentxmlfile""; filename=""" & file.GetFileName(filePath) & """" & vbCrLf
    body = body & "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    body = body & file.OpenTextFile(filePath).ReadAll & vbCrLf
    body = body & "-----------------------------7e0dd540448--" & vbCrLf
    ' Send the form data body as the request body
    http.send body
```

I save the file as follows:

```
Dim fsT As Object
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
fsT.Position = 0
fsT.WriteText http.responseBody
fsT.SaveToFile savePath, 2
fsT.Close
```

Another response option in the api is to embed the pdf in an xml as base64 text, but that gives me the same result.
How can I fix this?

Edit:
I narrowed it down. The story goes wrong during submit. I converted xml response with powershell and the pdf is wrong.
Then I recreated the whole submit process in powershell, and voilá, the response contained a readable pdf.
I need to rethink how I push the file.

Comment: @KJ I don't have too much experience with vba, this is the nth ieration and maybe I overcomplicated it. What is the simplest method to save a base64 encoded web response as a pdf file with VBA?

Comment: That `file.OpenTextFile` doesn't look like the correct approach.  FileSystemObject isn't always too great with preserving encoding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359002/send-file-via-post-in-visual-basic and the code there under `'--- read file`   And the likely original source for that approach: https://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/

Comment: @TimWilliams you were right, the issue was at reading back the saved xml. I did not find any reliable method to read the special Hungarian characters like íáé etc. So, I ended up not using the saved file but the text content of the XML object I used to generate the file. Looks like the submint form doesn't care if that's a real file or not.